# Driveraccess.dll missing from Visual Studio Assemblies

Tags: c#, ascom

I'm trying to compile the C# sample project from Ascom website: 
http://ascom-standards.org/.

However, `using DriverAccess;` gives me problems since the compiler cannot locate the dll in the path specified at installation (all done automatically).
Conformance checker validates my Ascom Platform (the latest, 6 sp1).
I can't figure how to solve this.

Comment: Have you checked the version number? If a version is explicitly defined, then the compiler will not connect to an older or newer version of the dll. It's possible they've released a new version of the dll since the example was created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add the reference.  Project + Add Reference, Browse tab, navigate to c:\program files (x86)\common files\ascom.net and pick ASCOM.DriverAccess.dll.  Drop the (x86) part of the path if your dev machine runs a 32-bit operating system.  The namespace name is "ASCOM.DriverAccess", not "DriverAccess"  so that's another possible hang-up.

I suspect you'll need more help, this isn't the friendliest wrapper.  Be sure to find fellow programmers in the dedicated [Yahoo group](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/ASCOM-Talk/), you are much more likely to get a quick response than here at SO.

Comment: You have been helpful. I'm actually not experienced at all with C#, I just approached it due to ASCOM facilities for .NET programming. I'll probably check the Yahoo group out.